# Qt5 - ASSERT: "bytesTransferred == writeChunkBuffer.size()"

Tags: c++, serial-port, qt5

I've written a tool which uses the QSerialPort to write to a serial device. It runs for a certain time until I get the following error message:

> ASSERT: "bytesTransferred == writeChunkBuffer.size()" in file
>   qserialport_win.cpp, line 511

My sending function looks like this:

```
/**
 * @brief Send text to device
 * @param text
 * @return Success/Fail
 */
bool Serial::send(QString text)
{
    if (connectionStatus && qsp.isWritable()) {
        QByteArray buffer = text.toLatin1();

        if (buffer.size() != qsp.write(buffer))
            qDebug() << "Send does not work";

        qsp.flush();
        msleep(15);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If I understand it correctly I write the text (which is around 20 chars) with flush to the device, wait 15ms and repeat it afterwards. I don't really understand why I get this message?

// EDIT:

After some time I figured out what the problem was. I forgot to mention, why I wait 15 ms. That was part of the documentation, to wait after I send the data. The biggest problem, related to sending data was, that I run QSerialPort in a separate thread. By using that I run in trouble. I moved it to the MainThread and use signal slot design by Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the API you're using or how it works, there is no inherent reason why a `write()` method should transfer all the data supplied, *especially* when it returns a write count: a clear signal that it may not transfer everything in one go.

The only problem is the assertion itself. You should *loop* until the data is written, not assume it is all written in a single write. Nor should you sleep between writes, in a vain attempt to outguess the device you're sending to. This is literally just a waste of time.